# create section in Dynamic UITableView in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I want to create Dynamic UITableView that's contain days as a sections (sat,sun,mon,...)

would you please helping me!
Thanks in advance!

here is my code but i don't know what should I write for creating sections:

Day.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Day : UIViewController 

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *monthTitle;

@end
```

Day.m

```
@synthesize monthTitle;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
   monthTitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
return self;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [self.monthTitle count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];



return cell;

}



 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle   
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{
    [self.monthTitle removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]  
 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}   
}




#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
/*
 <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib   
name#>" bundle:nil];
 // ...
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
 */
}

@end
```

Comment: Where is your `UITableView`?  Did you build it in interface builder?

Answer (score 14):

Make sure that you set up your `UIViewController` as the `delegate` and `dataSource` of the `UITableView`.  First you need to implement the protocols for these two:

```
@interface Day : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *monthTitle;

@end
```

Second you need to assign the `delegate` and `dataSource` of the `UITableView` to the `UIViewController`.

Right click on the `UITableView` and drag the `delegate` and `dataSource` outlets to the `UIViewController` at icon at the bottom of the view:

[image]

Now your `UITableView` is set up to use your `UIViewController` as the `delegate` and `dataSource`.  After that, set up the functions properly to fill the `UITableView` with data:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.monthTitle count];
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.monthTitle objectAtIndex:section];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;  //Return the number of sections you want in each row
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Whatever You Put For Cell Identifier On Interface Builder";
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    //Configure the cell however you wish

    return cell;
}
```

Now, assuming you have `self.monthTitle` set up as an `NSArray` of `NSString` that holds the titles you want for each section, this code will give you a `UITableView` with as many sections as there are titles in `self.monthTitle` with 1 row in each section and a section header that correlates to that particular index of `self.monthTitle`.  So if `self.monthTitle` holds all of the days of the week,  your `UITableView` will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The following method returns the number of sections.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}
```

So, if you need 3 sections, you have to return 3.

After that, you can use this method to name sections :

```
 - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        if(section == 0)
            return @"name section 0";
        else if(section == 1){
            return @"name section 1";
        }else
            return @"name section 2";
         //etc...
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use Array or dictionary to create dynamic structure

```
_sections = [NSMutableArray array];
            [_sections addObject:@"section1"];
            [_sections addObject:@"section2"];

    _rows = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray* section1 = [NSMutableArray array];
    [section1 addObject:@"row1"];
    [section1 addObject:@"row2"];
    NSMutableArray* section2 = [NSMutableArray array];
    [section1 addObject:@"row1"];
    [section1 addObject:@"row2"];
    [_rows addObject:section1];
    [_rows addObject:section2];

    #pragma mark - Table view data source

    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return [_sections count];
    }

    -(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [_sections objectAtIndex:section];
    }

    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [[_rows objectAtIndex:section] count];
    }

    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
        if(!cell)
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:nil];
        cell.textLabel.text = [[_rows objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: @Nomad where should I put _sections and _row staff because I will get an error

Comment: Add to the declaration of class